# PY_VAR0 using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

today = date.today()
todays_date = date.today()
next_year = today.year + 1

class BirthdayFrame(ttk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, padding="10 10 10 10")
    self.pack()

    # define string variables for text entry
    self.birthday_text = tk.StringVar()
    self.days_until = tk.StringVar()

    # display the grid of components
    ttk.Label(self, text = "Enter Birthday(MM/DD): ",
              foreground="purple").grid(
        column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.E)
    ttk.Entry(self, width=30, textvariable=self.birthday_text).grid(
        column=1, row=0)

    ttk.Label(self, text = "Days Until/Since Birthday: ",
              foreground="purple").grid(
        column=0, row=2, sticky=tk.E)
    ttk.Entry(self, width=30, textvariable=self.calculate,
              state = "readonly").grid(
        column=1, row=2)

    ttk.Button(self, text="Calculate Days",
               command=self.calculate).grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=tk.E)

  def calculate(self):
    # get the birthday from the entry field
    birthday_text = input(self.birthday_text).strip()
    birthday = datetime.strptime(birthday_text, "%m/%d")
    birthday = birthday.replace(year=today.year + 1)

    # calculate days until birthday
    days = (datetime.now()- birthday).days
    days_until = ((birthday-datetime.now()).days)-365
    days_past = (((birthday-datetime.now()).days)-365)-(days_until*2)
    
    if days_until>0:
        print(f"Your birthday is in {days_until} days.")
    else:
        print(f"Your birthday was {days_past} days ago.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Days Until Your Birthday")
BirthdayFrame(root)
root.mainloop()
```

When running this code, I get PY_VAR0 each time. I know I am supposed to enter print(var.get()) somewhere, but I do not understand what it does or where I should enter it. If someone could help that would be amazing. I am trying to make a GUI where you enter your birthday MM/DD and tells you if it is upcoming or has passed in the current calendar year. If it has passed, it tells you how many days ago, and if it is upcoming, it should tell you how many days there are until your birthday.

Comment: Try changing `birthday_text = input(self.birthday_text).strip()` to `birthday_text = self.birthday_text.get().strip()`.

Comment: Also change `textvariable=self.calculate` in second `ttk.Entry` to `textvariable=self.days_until`. This will output the result to readonly entry tool. You will also have to replace print statements with `self.days_until.set(`.

Comment: @Derek thank you so much for the help that got rid of my PY_VAR0 problem! My only issue now, is it returns the days in the terminal, but says NONE in my GUI output. Do you know of anything I could do to fix that?

Comment: You're not getting or setting the values of your `StringVar`s properly — they are **not** just like Python string variables. See [The Variable Classes (BooleanVar, DoubleVar, IntVar, StringVar)](https://web.archive.org/web/20201031100214id_/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm).